# Javascript slice function returning different values for same value?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

im solving a question on hackerrank and i encountered a problem. my slice method is not returning the right value. I was able to recreate using console.log.

```js
console.log(+("9007199254740993"));

console.log("9007199254740993");
```

why do these return different values?

Comment: javascript has a limit to the precision of numbers.

Comment: i edited the code, would it still have a problem with that amount?

Comment: yes in your first example it is no longer a string but a number.

Comment: is there a way to bypass this? i need to change the string to a number to perform an operation

Comment: there are big number libraries out there.

Comment: You have the max here: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest value possible for a JavaScript number is [9007199254740991](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Integer_range_for_Number).

To deal with numbers larger than that you will need to use a [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

```js
const max = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
console.log(max);

const maxPlusTwo = max + 2;
console.log(maxPlusTwo);

const maxPlusTwoBigInt = BigInt("9007199254740993");
console.log(maxPlusTwoBigInt.toString());
```

[This link](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-BigInt) shows the current level of native support for BigInt.  Depending on your target platform you may need to use a polyfill for BigInt functionality.

Comment: This is likely an intentional part of the challenge; you might consider adding the numbers elementary-school style, "by hand", rather than using a library.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a maximum safe integer limit of `2^53 - 1` (`9,007,199,254,740,991`) - it is possible to have numbers greater than this, but it's not very good:

```js
console.log(9007199254740992 + 200000000001);
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

(The above snippet shows they are different - look at the fifth and last digits).

You would have to use an experimental [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) if you wanted bigger numbers.